# Sitecore 8, Crawling error for every item (Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

In the crawling.log I can see the following exception exist for every sitecore item. This is also making the sitecore content editor slow at startup.

```
6488 20:05:13 WARN  Could not compute value for ComputedIndexField: recommendation for indexable: sitecore://master/{8FD38E05-E13C-4D51-842F-877B5DA91E72}?lang=en&ver=1
Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.CreateObject(Type type, Object[] parameters)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetInnerObject(XmlNode paramNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.AssignProperties(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Object obj, Boolean assert, Boolean deferred, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.ReportingQueryBase..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Reporting.TimeRangeItemBasedReportingQuery..ctor(ID queryItemId, ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider, CachingPolicy cachingPolicy)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.Analytics.Reporting.TestPotentialQuery..ctor(ReportDataProviderBase reportProvider)
   at Sitecore.ContentTesting.ContentSearch.ComputedIndexFields.TestPotentialMetricBase.ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
   at Sitecore.ContentSearch.LuceneProvider.LuceneDocumentBuilder.AddComputedIndexFieldsInSequence()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.MongoDB
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Reporting.MongoDbReportDataSource..ctor(String connectionStringName)
```

I actually have no idea whats going wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you have a custom computed field called `recommendation` - check the code in there to see if you can track down the issue.

Comment: Yes, this field is in configuration for Sitecore Content Search. `Sitecore.ContentTesting.Lucene.IndexConfiguration`.  I removed this from configuration and the problem is solved now. Thanks!!!